# How to Dismiss Presenting View Controller when "Ok" Action Tapped in UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, dismiss, uialertaction

I'm trying to dismiss the current view controller in the completion handler of a UIAlertAction, but it is not dismissing. I have written the following code (The loading indicator is simply a loading alert controller that I dismiss when the data was successfully uploaded):

```
loadingIndicator.dismiss(animated: true) {                           
      let success = UIAlertController(title: "Successfully Uploaded", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
      let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { _ in
               print("Ok selected") //this is working correctly
               self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) //this is not
      })
                      
      success.addAction(ok)
      self.present(success, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

However, after clicking on "Ok" in the alert, "Ok selected" is printed but the view controller is not dismissed. Nothing else shows up in the debugger.

Comment: Try dismissing an alert on main thread.

Comment: I'm calling this code from another function because it's being called by a button. I also tried wrapping the dismiss in a `DispatchQueue.main.async` call but that also did not work.

Comment: Check if VC is presented?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Updated answer, I am sure it's something related to your navigation hierarchy.

Comment: VC is not being presented. Very confusing. I tried dismissing the success alert controller and then dismissing the VC in its completion but that is also not working.

Comment: The problem is your VC is not presented. It's pushed in navigation. you will have to present VC to dismiss it. You can't dismiss pushed VC.

Comment: Dismiss works on presented controller and Pop work on pushed controller.

Comment: dismiss was working outside the ok completion block for me.. also tried the main thread, still not working.. and the vc is presented (which is why dismiss worked initially)

Comment: i put a breakpoint inside the ok completion block and its not hitting the breakpoint.. also put a print inside it.. and its not getting called at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try dismissing it on Main thread and also check if ViewController is presented or pushed in navigation hierarchy.

```
loadingIndicator.dismiss(animated: true) {
    let success = UIAlertController(title: "Successfully Uploaded", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
             // If pushed use PopViewController on navigation
             // self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
    })
    success.addAction(ok)
    self.present(success, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

To check if ViewController is being presented or not use `self.isBeingPresented` property.